# How to deploy Django 1.3?

Tags: python, django, passenger

I'm triyng to deploy old Django 1.3 application.
Webserver is Phusion Passenger.
I have created passenger_wsgi.py

```
import imp
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', '/home/gian/public_html/test/gian/wsgi.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

and wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Webserver started the application, but after I got

```
ImportError at /
No module named gian.urls
```

I suppose an issue in location files.
When I edited settings.py and specified urls instead gian.urls I got next error that no module named gian.

Comment: Why are you doing all that complex stuff inside passenger_wsgi.py? The [passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/wsgi_spec.html) have a much simpler example.

Comment: Because that was done when I pointed wsgi file in cpanel